# Distinguish between app login and web login to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a iOS app that writes data to Firease-database. The iOS-app uses Firebase Authentication with Email/password. 
The web-app also uses Firebase Auth. But I don´t want the iOS-users to be able to log in to the web-app. Is there a way to separate the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simples way to achieve this is to add a new field for each user named `os` (operatiing system) with value of `iOs` or `web`, according to the operation system from which the user creates the account. When the users creates an account from an iOs device, then you need to set the value to `iOs`. The same thing for `web`.

When a users wants to log in, you just need to verify what kind of user it is. If the user has set the value to iOs and he tries to log in via web, then don't allow it. And vice versa.

Hope it helps.